# error: expected primary - expression before float

Tags: c++

So I am trying to learn cpp and have been stuck here for a while. Google alot but no solution. Hope someone helps me out here. made changes it but cant fix it.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main()

{
    
float a , b , c ;
    
cout << "Enter a number "<<endl;
    
cin >> a ;
    
cout << "Enter another number "<<endl;
    
cin >> b ;
    
cout << "The remainder of the two numbers is " << float a % float b; //error here
    
return 0;

}
```

Comment: I think you skipped an early chapter in your text-book about how to use variables. You do e.g. `cin >> a` but then `cout << float a` (basically). How does that make sense? Should it be `cin >> float a` and `cout << float a`, or `cin >> a` and `cout << a` for you to be consistent? Note that one or the alternatives is *wrong*.

Comment: *Google alot but no solution* -- C++ is properly learned by using good C++ books, not google.

Comment: Not sure what you were searching for, but pretty much any C++ docs/tutorials that discuss writing data to stdout will show how to do this--try searching for "c++ write variable to cout" (or stdout) etc and you should find helpful examples :)

Comment: One thing you're going to find is it is extremely hard to google programming syntax. Unless you know the formal names, and the name can change in different contexts (for example `*` can mean multiply, dereference a pointer, declare a pointer, and anything else the programmer decides `*` means for a given object) so you really need to have a good set of reference texts.

Answer (score 1):

The *remainder* operator `%` is only applicable to integral types in C++.

You can use `std::fmod(a, b)` for the floating point modulus:

```
std::cout << "The remainder of the two numbers is " << std::fmod(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put type names in expression.

```
cout << "The remainder of the two numbers is " << a % b;
```

If you want to do c-style casting, add parenthesis around the type name. (In this case casting to `float` is meaningless because `a` and `b` are already `float`)

```
cout << "The remainder of the two numbers is " << (float) a % (float) b;
```

Using cast expressions like `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` is better for casting in C++. (again this is meaningless here)

```
cout << "The remainder of the two numbers is " << static_cast<float>(a) % static_cast<float(b);
```

Comment: Perhaps mentioning that floating point modulus can't be done with the built-in `operator%` would be good. `std::fmod(a, b)` would work though.

Comment: It says fmod is not a member of std

Comment: Add `#include <cmath>`